# cake/basics.php missing when cloning a project

Tags: php, cakephp

I tried to clone `beta.neighborrow.com` - I copied the directory file for file but I'm getting this error on the new URL `instillbliss.neighborrow.com`:

> Warning: require(cake/basics.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/neighborrow/instillbliss.neighborrow.com/index.php on line 53
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'cake/basics.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear:/home/neighborrow/instillbliss.neighborrow.com:/home/neighborrow/instillbliss.neighborrow.com/app/') in /home/neighborrow/instillbliss.neighborrow.com/index.php on line 53

I found the right file thanks to Ahmed...

```
*/
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}

/**
 * The absolute path to the "cake" directory, WITHOUT a trailing DS.
 *
 */
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', '/home/neighborrow');
}

/**
 * Editing below this line should NOT be necessary.
 * Change at your own risk.
 *
 */
if (!defined('WEBROOT_DIR')) {
    define('WEBROOT_DIR', basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

I am assuming that I have to change `/home/neighborrow`, but what should I change it to? Is that the database?

Comment: This basically means that `cake/basics.php` is missing.

Comment: but i have the same exact files here beta.neighborrow.com and there is no cake folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to reconfigure the paths in the webroot/index.php file
and make sure you have set the right permissions on the cake folder

Comment: ok awesome... i found the right file... ill update the question now